# Does angular-cli support rc5?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I downloaded and installed ("npm install") the most up2date angular2 project with rc5 dependencies from [angular2 quickstart on github](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).
I saw that [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server)'s package has rc4 dependencies on their github.

**How does one install angular-cli that support rc5 dependencies?**

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1640

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the version tagged as `webpack` via...

```
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

make sure you uninstall any current version you have locally first via...

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

Note that this will move into the default install (sans `@webpack`) prior to final release

Comment: what next? (I'm very begginer with all those configurations). should I run "ng init" ?

Comment: You can find info here: https://cli.angular.io/ and more detailed info here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli but since you want RC5 please remember the `@webpack` when installing

Comment: Unfortunately what you will get is reams of errors complaining with ERR! about everything from the OS to Node to being unable to find python, and a few pages more. Stick with beta.10 until they've tested it on, say, two boxes. that aren't the developer machines.

Comment: @RickO'Shea If you're having issues, please submit a question here, or an issue on the cli repo (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/new)

Comment: I use SystemJS... will I be able to use the webpack version of the angular-cli without too many issues?

Comment: @DanielPatrick you can follow the instructions here to update to the webpack version https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/cacaa4eff10e135016ef81076fab1086a3bce92f/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md

Comment: @Brocco I guess I meant- if I start using the Webpack version to generate/serve/test in my existing SystemJS project- will that harm anything?  Further- is Angular 2 as a whole just heading in the Webpack direction? should I consider switching over?

Comment: @DanielPatrick Harm anything? No. While it is not the direction of angular, it *is* the direction of the CLI. It is released under `@webpack` for now as bugs are worked through, but the plan is to move it over to the main release  before the final release. I would suggest switching your app(s) over to that version.

Answer (score 6):

I had significant issues when trying to use the webpack update. If you do as well, you can alternatively still use the beta.10 version of the CLI with RC5 without too much trouble until they get some of the problems ironed out.

Create a new project, if you don't already have one. In the project's package.json file, update all of the angular dependencies to RC5, like so:

```
...
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "^0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
...
```

Save the package.json, and then, run `npm install`.

After that, you will manually have to set up a module for your app and update its bootstrapper. To see how to do this: visit Angular's official [RC4 to RC5 migration guide.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)

You can use the CLI to build, serve, test, and create new components, services as usual, but the way you import dependencies is different, as per RC5.

See also:

[Angular Modules Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

[Updating Your Angular 2 App From RC4 to RC5](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/)

Comment: Please submit issues you've had to the angular-cli repo... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/new

Comment: The issues have already been reported by others. I am waiting for buxfixes.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can not deploy your app using ng github-pages:deploy. 
I created a new app using `ng new`, using the new cli webpack (1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2) for RC5. And I get errors while deploying
Error: ng github-pages:deploy throws the error: "no angular cli-build.js found"

Even after manual deploy, I get error of `Can't bind to 'property' since it isn't a known property of 'component'`